# Font true type and OTF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, fonts

I'm currently at my school and I have prepared program that is using OTF font (It works at home). But unfortunately at school it's not working properly, I mean program works but looks not right. I would like to ask how to get it working?

I tried:

```
     lblName.Font = new Font("fontname",size,FontStyle)
```

But unfortunately I don't know how to check font name to be searched properly, some fonts are named different (Mine is Panton Black Caps). My visual studio is 2013 edition, any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the OTF font installed on the school's machine?

Comment: @Übercoder yes it is.